# Variable assignment outside of case statement

Tags: bash, shell, assignment, case

In many languages it is possible to assign the result of a case/switch statement to a variable, rather than repeating the variable assignment many times within the case statement.  Is it possible to do something like this in the Bash shell?

```
color_code=$(case "$COLOR" in
  (red)    1;;
  (yellow) 2;;
  (green)  3;;
  (blue)   4;;
esac)
```

(Or, as an aside, in any other shells?)

Comment: You have extra `(`s. Otherwise, it's fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `variable=$(...)` construct will take the standard output of whatever command is in `$(...)` and assign it to `variable`. Thus, to get `variable` assigned the way that you want, the values have to be sent to standard output.  This is easily done with the `echo` command:

```
color_code=$(case "$COLOR" in
  red)    echo 1;;
  yellow) echo 2;;
  green)  echo 3;;
  blue)   echo 4;;
esac)
```

This will work on `bash` as well as all other POSIX shells.

#### The Optional Left Parens

According to the POSIX standard, the left parens in a `case` statement is optional and the following works as well:

```
color_code=$(case "$COLOR" in
  (red)    echo 1;;
  (yellow) echo 2;;
  (green)  echo 3;;
  (blue)   echo 4;;
esac)
```

As Gilles points out in the comments, not all shells accept both forms in combination with `$(...)`: for an impressively detailed table of compatibility, see ["$( )" command substitution vs. embedded ")"](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/cmd-subst/).

Comment: One page I checked (I don't recall where it was) listed the opening `(` as optional.  I thought it might help avoid letting the `)` be misinterpreted as the closing `)` for the `$(...)` expression.

Comment: @iconoclast Yes.  The opening `(` are optional: the code works the same without or without them.  I left them off only because, for better or worse, that is tradition.  The key part of the proposed solution is the use of `echo`.

Comment: @iconoclast Older (pre-POSIX) shells didn't allow an opening `(` for `case` patterns, but some shells did and required the opening `(` when `case` is used in a command substitution. Modern shells are fine either way. See http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/cmd-subst/

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for that info.  The depth of your knowledge is, as always, impressive.

Answer (score 3):

`color_code=$(…)` assigns the output of the `…` command to the variable `color_code`, with final newlines stripped off. So you need to produce some output. The code you wrote attempts to execute `1` as a command.

You can use this idiom. Note that `color_code` will be empty if `$COLOR` is none of the supported values.

```
color_code=$(case "$COLOR" in
  (red)    echo 1;;
  (yellow) echo 2;;
  (green)  echo 3;;
  (blue)   echo 4;;
esac)
```

But it isn't very idiomatic. The shell language is geared towards simple combinations of simple commands. This big command substitution is awkward. The command substitution creates a subshell, which is slower than the straightforward method:

```
case "$COLOR" in
  red)    color_code=1;;
  yellow) color_code=2;;
  green)  color_code=3;;
  blue)   color_code=4;;
esac
```

The main semantic difference between the two approaches is that `$(…)` creates a subshell, so that any assignment, exit, redirection, etc. that is performed inside has no effect outside.